# Compare 2 arrays and get row number of matching value in GAS

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I have 2 sheets, sheet4 contains a range of dates, in this case 20 of them, sheet1 contains 7 of these dates from sheet4 after I filtered out the duplicates. I need to compare these two arrays and get the row number of the matching values on sheet1.

Sheet1 values:

[image: sheet1]

Sheet4 values:

[image]

I need to check which row number on `sheet1` is corresponding to the value on `sheet4`. For example, `"F1"` on sheet4 would give me the value of `2` (as of row 2), and `"F5"` `"F6"` and `"F7"` which are all `07/11/2019 06:10` would all give me the value of `3`.
I need the corresponding row numbers in an array as well, so I can use them later on next to the sheet4 dates.

I can't seem to figure it out how to write the code for it, as the arrays are different length.

**Edit:** My code so far. It returns the row numbers of sheet one multiple times, in an order, like: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

```
var sheet4Array = ' array on sheet 4 column F';
var sheet1Values = 'values on sheet 1 in an array';
var rowMM = ' row numbers on sheet 1';


var sheet1Array = []; // sheet 1 array
var ss1Arr = [];
for (var p = 0; p < sheet4Array.length; p++) {
   for (var s = 0; s < sheet1Values.length; s++) {
      if (sheet4Array[p].indexOf(sheet1Values[s])) {
      var sheet1A = rowMM[s];
       sheet1Array .push(sheet1A);
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Why do you need this in script? You can do this with built-in formulas in Google Sheets.